# geom_bar with large number of discrete values not showing bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a data frame `df` I have a large number of discrete values for `metric` and their counts `cnt`

I wanted to get a `bar plot` of the counts for each discrete value of `metric`.

So I do the following,

```
df <- read.csv("metric.csv", header=T)
df$metric <- as.factor(df$metric)
ggplot(df, aes(x=metric, y=cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

With the above I get an empty plot like below with this - why ?

The data I used for the data frame `df` is here - http://wikisend.com/download/569376/metric.csv

How do I get a bar plot out of this data ?

[image]

Comment: Try changing `scale_y_continuous` limits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not immediately aware of any limitations of geom_bar, but it is unsurprising that this doesn't work very well -- I interrupted it on my machine, so I don't even know what it looks like when it finishes rendering.

Are you sure that a bar plot is appropriate for this data?  Which is to say, is the "metric" column effectively a factor?

Running a scatter plot completes rapidly with results that might be more useful (here using a log scale because a linear scale is hurt by the outlier)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=metric, y=cnt) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: The `metric` column holds discrete possible values for a metric and `cnt` col holds the number of occurrences with a particular value.